# Framer Page Transition does not fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, transition, framer-motion

I'm using nextjs 13 and i'm trying to make a page transition.
This is my Code:

```
// layout.tsx

// ...
<DetectRouteChange>{children}</DetectRouteChange>
// ...
```

```
// detectRouteChange.tsx
// I need this because AnimatePresence needs to be in a Client Component

'use client';
// ...
return (<AnimatePresence>{children}</AnimatePresence>)
// ...
```

```
// page.tsx

// ...
<Construct>
// Page Content
</Construct>
```

```
// construct.tsx
// I need this because motion.div needs to be in a Client Component

// ...
const pathname = usePathname();
return (
        <div>
            <motion.div
                className="fixed w-screen h-screen bg-black grid place-items-center z-50"
                initial={{ top: '0px' }}
                animate={{ top: '-100vh' }}
                exit={{top: '0px'}}
                transition={{
                    duration: 0.5,
                    delay: 1,
                    ease: [0.55, 0, 0.1, 1],
                }}
                key={pathname}
            >
                <Image
                    src="/assets/logo.svg"
                    width="50"
                    height="50"
                    alt="Logo"
                    className=""
                ></Image>
            </motion.div>
            <div className="mt-3 p-5">
                <Navbar></Navbar>
            </div>
            {children}
            <div className="mt-3 p-5">
                <Footer></Footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Why does the "exit" animation not fire when i change the route? (maybe it fires and i don't see it but it doesn't work anyways)

thanks in advance :)